# Reversing a word in C and then storing that reversed word to use in a printf

Tags: c, for-loop, printf, reverse, c-strings

So basically I'm trying to reverse a word (a single word, not a string with multiple words) and I've managed to reverse the word using this

```
{
    int end, x;
    end = strlen(myString) - 1;
    for (x = end; x >= 0; --x) {
        printf("%c", myString[x]);
    }
}
```

(myString is defined somewhere else in the code)

But here's the kicker, I need to print the reversed word like this:

```
printf("The word reversed is '%c'", myString);
```

And I've no idea how to actually take the word reversed by the for loop and putting it into the second printf command. Any ideas?

Comment: Use `%s` instead

Comment: that just diddnt print anything

Comment: Check is the first char of the string a `\0`, that one should remain at the end, it is added to signal that there is no more text

Comment: If `myString` contains `n` characters, then the character at `myString[0]` needs to become the character at `myString[n - 1]` and vice versa. You would normally use a temporary variable to store one of the characters, then replace it by the other character, and finally setting the other character to the temporary one. Repeat for `myString[1]` and `myString[n - 2]`, etc. You only need to iterate from 0 to n / 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are.

```
for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( myString ); i < n / 2; i++ )
{
    char c = myString[i];
    myString[i] = myString[n - i - 1];
    myString[n - i - 1] = c;
}

printf("The word reversed is '%s'\n", myString);
```

Comment: You have some small typos. mtString -> myString and the `\n` is before the `'` instead of after.

Comment: yeah i fixed the typos and it worked, thanks :D

Comment: @Cheatah Thanks. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

If the string you are passed is a literal instead of an allocated pointer, you'll need to make a reverse-copy of the string into an allocated buffer.  Same applies if you are trying to avoid corrupting the orignial string.

```
// allocate a buffer big enough to hold a copy of the string
int len = strlen(myString);
char* reverse = malloc(len+1);

// reverse copy it over.
for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++)
{
    reverse[i] = myString[len-1-i];
}
reverse[len] = '\0'; // null terminate our new string

printf("Reversed word: %s\n", reverse);

// free the string when you are done with it
free(reverse);
```

Comment: this was the last time i used the string in my code so doesnt matter what the string contains after the reversing